# Finding (X1,Y1) coordinates around circle with center point (X,Y) and radius R

Tags: java

I wanted to find all points of a circle with angle of 30 degree and radius r, when i am given center of circle (x,y) till we scan entire 360 degree.

Please let me know if i can use any java library related to this.

Code below :
I have written code as below :

```
<code>
    double xpos = xPosition;
            double ypos = yPosition;
            double step = 2 * Math.PI / 20;
            double radius = 50;
            List<DevicePositions> listdevicePos = new ArrayList<DevicePositions>();
            DevicePositions devicePos = null;
            for (double theta = 0; theta < 2 * Math.PI; theta += step) {
                double x = xpos + radius * Math.cos(theta);
                double y = ypos - radius * Math.sin(theta);
                devicePos = new DevicePositions();
                devicePos.setxCoordinate(x);
                devicePos.setyCoordinate(y);

                listdevicePos.add(devicePos);
            }

</code>
```

Thanks
Brijesh

Comment: *"find all points of a circle"*, circles have an unlimited number of points.

Comment: Are you looking for the points at integral coordinates?

Comment: What is the 30 degree angle? As far as I know, circles are not defined in terms of angles. Anyway, it doesn't sound like you would need a library for this. Should be a one-line equation. But hard to say what it is you're looking for.

Comment: Are you looking for 12 points, like a clock with numbers around the center with equal intervals of 30°?

Comment: Yes i want all points with 30 degree angle that means 12 points

Comment: So you already have code. What's wrong with it? What are you asking, exactly?

Comment: Actually earlier code was not working, and was going into infinite loop. So i have fixed it and its working fine now.